# Linksys Wireless N Router, Wireless vs Wired Internet Speed Issue

Tags: wireless-networking, speed, internet-connection, wireless-router

I have a Linksys wireless N router and I am having some issues with my internet speed.

When wired to the router I get a down speed of about 20mbs, but when I switch to use wireless I get only 1mbs. But oddly I get the same 4mbs up on either connection.

I am using the stock settings outside having tried different channels and switching to Google's DNS.

I can understand that wireless would lose some of the 100 some mbs, but enough to drop the internet to 1mbs from 20mbs seems wrong. Just curious if anyone has any thoughts?

Thank you.

Comment: Just for future reference, changing your DNS servers to Google will have zero effect on your actual bandwidth (aside from possibly mis-directing you to non-local speedtest servers).

Comment: It would be useful to know if the problem is on the router or the host. Does this phenomenon happen to any device connected wirelessly to your router, or is it specific to one particular host computer?

Comment: It happens to all my devices when they are on the wireless.

Answer (score 0):

Three possibilities come to mind immediately:

1. Try a different channel (as you hinted it) so that you'll be on different frequencies.  If your neighbours have wireless routers also, then many of them could also be using the default channel which means you'd all be competing for channel 6 (most likely that channel anyway).
2. Your router is getting too hot.  Make sure it's in a well-ventilated area.  If the bottom (or any part of it) feels hot to the touch, then it may be too hot.  Check the manual for temperature recommendations.
3. An updated firmware might be available for download from the vendor's web site.  This is normally a free download, and improvements in major version updates often include fixes for various problems related to connectivity.

Comment: To add onto this, update drivers for your wireless card as well. Also make sure that there are no interfering devices nearby (microwave, fluorescent lighting, wireless phones, non-shielded speakers, etc) as these can have serious effects over wireless functionality.

Comment: Tried the channels, and everything has the most up to date firmware. I will try moving it tonight, but I don't think that is the issue. The only thing near it is the cable modem and it has a good deal of air flow around it.